# Question about architecture of microservices over http for Nestjs

Tags: microservices, nestjs

Nestjs [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics) state: "In Nest, a microservice is fundamentally an application that uses a different transport layer than HTTP."

That is a possible, and possibly a fancy way of implementing microservices, but I want to start my experiment simple. Just build an app that has 2 or 3 services in their own docker container. With their own mongo-db (in another separate container). Then have these communicate with rest-api calls.

Let's say an auth-service, a post-service and a comment-service for instance.

If I want those to be separate entities, in their own container, do I just create 3 separate applications with cli: `nest new <service-name>` ? That will give me full apps, with appmodules etc etc. It should work, but is that the recommended way to do this?

I tried googling, and looking through docs, but maybe this question is just too basic, so no one bothers to write anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's definitely an option. The thing to be aware of with an approach of microservices over HTTP is that then the endpoint is pretty much exposed to public traffic. If you use services like RabbitMQ or Redis, then there's no public facing endpoint that can be hit and has to be secured, only the API gateway to worry about.

But for your question: yes, that approach is fine and is probably the best way to go about it, unless you want to make a monorepo and keep them all in the same repo (I'd suggest [Nx](https://nx.dev) if that's the route you're going)

Comment: Thx for that tip, I had never heard of it. I guess, when putting th containers in somthing like it should not be too hard to put all but one BE service inside private subnet for instance, and then with reasonable loadbalancer settings I'd be on my way at least. Thx again!